# base64 image is broken when trying to render image in headertemplate puppeteer

Tags: base64, handlebars.js, puppeteer, pdf-generation

I want to create a pdf using puppeteer/[PDFOptions](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.pdfoptions) . It contains a base64 encoded image inside the *headerTemplate*:

```js
await page.pdf({
  displayHeaderFooter: true,
  printBackground: true,
  headerTemplate:
    '<img class="header-logo" src="data:image/png;base64,${headerimgtry}" style="height:100px; width:100px">',
  footerTemplate: '<h1">Footer</h1>',
  margin: "30px",
  format: "A4",
  path: "output.pdf",
});
```

[(source)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ss50N.png)

But instead of the image it only shows a placeholder:

[image]

How can I correctly display the image in the pdf?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a different templating engine and recently came across this issue.  Escaping `img/png` with a forward-slash to `img//png` fixed it for me.